# PHP transfer file to another server that requires key authentication

Tags: php

Is there a way that I can transfer a binary file (image, pdf and etc) from server A to server B via PHP, where server B requires public key authentication rather than a password to access.

The private key in server A will reside outside of the web server root document.

Comment: Transfer  via which protocol ?

Comment: any suggestion? I've checked server B, vsftpd: unrecognized service

Comment: You can add some key  by adding meta-data for your files

Comment: Googeling something trivial like “php public key authentication” would have led you straight to http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-pubkey-file.php, and when you look around on that page you see that f.e. `ssh2_scp_send` also exists ...

Comment: @CBroe, can I combine this fopen?
ftp is installed when I used `ps aux | grep ftp`

Comment: Part of the reason you're getting negative reactions to this question is that it's really two questions: 1) How do I transfer a file from one server to another? (Answer: there are many ways, which ones are available will depend on your server set up.) 2) Can I / how do I use file transfer method X in PHP? Obviously, we can't answer question 2 until we know your decision from question 1, and we can't answer question 1 with so little information about your system (you haven't even said if you're using Windows, Linux, or something completely different). It just doesn't fit as a neat Q&A topic.

Comment: If server B offers "public key authentication", that suggests the protocol and access method is already determined. Why are you poking around vsftpd and whatnot? Sounds like you need to access the server over ***SSH***!?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
shell_exec('rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /location-of-your-key/rsa" /location-of-your-image/image.jpg user@111.111.111.111:/location-where-you-want-to-put-image-in-server-b/');
```

Where `111.111.111.111` is server B IP address

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php